# Kaldi: Transfer learning

Tags: speech-recognition, kaldi

I'm trying to do transfer learning on Kaldi-ASR with a model that has been pretrained on Common Voice, with a custom limited vocabulary dataset. However, I have found the documentation to be quite limited wrt the config file to be provided to `egs/commonvoice/s5/steps/online/nnet2/prepare_online_decoding_retrain.sh`.

For reference, these are the kind of parameters I have provided

```
steps/online/nnet2/prepare_online_decoding_transfer.sh --cmd run.pl --config s5/exp/chain/tdnn1a_sp_online/conf/online_cmvn.conf  --stage 0 s5/exp/chain/tdnn1a_sp_online/  s5/data/lang/ s5/exp/chain/tdnn1a_sp_online/ s5/exp/chain/nnet_transfer
```

The error that I'm currently getting is

```
steps/online/nnet2/prepare_online_decoding_transfer.sh: no such file <folder-path>/s5/exp/chain/tdnn1a_sp_online/conf/online_nnet2_decoding.conf
```

Obviously I need to create this file but I don't know how. It would be great if I could have some pointers on how to create this and what config parameters to supply. If any additional information is required, please let me know in the comments.

TIA.

Comment: prepare_online_decoding.sh script creates that that config.file

Comment: If I understand your comment correctly, to run prepare_online_decoding.sh, we need a file that is *generated* by running prepare_online_decoding.sh?

Comment: No, to run prepare_online_decoding_**transfer**.sh you need to run prepare_online_decoding.sh. Those are different scripts.